# DataTable or dataTable?

Tags: datatables

On the DataTables website there are a number of examples given for functions on a table.  In some they use:

```
table = $('#example').dataTable();
```

in others...

```
table = $('#example').DataTable();
```

It took me a while to notice that some functions work only on the former, while others only on the later.  This is really confusing and I haven't been able to find any clarification on the difference between the two.

Currently I am at a standstill as I require two functions that only work on one or the other:

```
table.fnAdjustColumnSizing
```

and

```
table.column(x).search(this.value).draw();
```

Anyone have an idea for how to build the table so both of the above can work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DataTable` (uppercase first letter) indicates a method from the new api. The latest versions of DataTables still support the old methods, but you should use the new api when possible.

http://datatables.net/manual/api#Accessing-the-API

This is probably what you need for your question:

```
table.columns.adjust().draw();
```

https://datatables.net/reference/api/columns.adjust()

Comment: thanks.. Since google searches return examples for both old and new it's been a bit confusing.  I've found that `table.column(x).search(this.value).draw();` can be rewritten for the new API as `$('#example).DataTable.columns(x).search(this.value).draw();` and it works.

Answer (score 2):

See the upgrade facts -> http://www.datatables.net/upgrade/1.10-faqs

> Q. I get an error message when trying to access one of the old fn*
>   style API methods A. This is the inverse of the above issue.
>   DataTables 1.9 attached a number of functions (all starting with fn)
>   to the jQuery object. The old API is still available, but you must use
>   $().dataTable() to access the jQuery object.

Simply use

```js
$(window).bind('resize', function () {
    $('#example').dataTable().fnAdjustColumnSizing();
});
```

see demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/uL5x4dg1/** if you want to use the old API functions along with the new `DataTable()` API. `dataTable()` does not reinitialise the table, it just returns the oldstyle jQuery object.